# Difference between @"foo" and stringWithFormat

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pros and Cons of using [NSString stringWithString:@“some string”] versus @“some string”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275131/pros-and-cons-of-using-nsstring-stringwithstringsome-string-versus-some)

What is the difference between using

```
   @"foo"
```

and

```
   [NSString stringWithFormat: @"foo"];
```

Thank you

Comment: @Monolo, I dont know if they're different at all, so I guess difference in usage?

Answer (score 0):

None, you'll get the same result (cut the `;` at the end of the second line of code to make them equivalent)

Comment: No you don't, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275131/pros-and-cons-of-using-nsstring-stringwithstringsome-string-versus-some/8275225#8275225 You get different objects back and lose some of the efficiencies of `@"foo"`

Comment: Why not? Besides the underlying things that make the string constant more efficient (that I don't think he's interested in since he asked such a question) he will get the same result/effect.

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat: @"foo"]` creates a new object (and the `@"foo"` string) every time it is called. That is quite a big difference to `@"foo"` which just exists once throughout the programme.