# Objective C why format string as string

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, nsstring

While working on project code left to me by a previous dev, I have encountered the following construct

```
-(NSString *)StringCheckWithString:(NSString *)string{

    NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", string];

    if([string2 length] == 0){
        return @"none";
    }
    else {
        return string2;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why you would do this, it seems significantly overengineered to me and I don't understand why it has been done this way (for clarity, I don't understand why the string is formatted like this, I understand the length check)

Comment: It's possible `string` is an unknown input. If it contains format characters and you use it raw, BAD THINGS can happen.

Comment: @thegrinner surely in the case `string` contains format characters, `string2` now also contains those characters?

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around a situation where an NSString being passed to a method ISN'T REALLY an NSString. Does anyone have a specific example how to achieve that situation?

Comment: That's likely the exact reasoning. If someone blindly used a string that had format characters they could be misinterpreted as actually being format characters (instead of some sort of input that just happened to match that style). That could be bad. The only extra bit in that method seems to be the reaction when it's a zero length string - that might be to avoid issues accessing a `nil` string. The method as a whole looks like something to sanitize user input.

Comment: Hmmm....  Why was my comment deleted???  I pointed out that the effect of `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", string]` (if it's really needed) can be achieved much more cheaply with `[string description]`.  Though you far too often see the stringWithFormat thing used where it's entirely unnecessary -- it's like bad DNA that gets copied form one generation to the next.

Comment: @thegrinner I'm struggling with what you mean, as this method doesn't sanitize `string`. I understand (and expected) a method to check for 0-length (0-length strings break another bit of the code). However, I just ran a quick test and `[string isEqualToString:string2]` returns `true`. Unless you mean this is a poor attempt to sanitize user input.

Comment: And it should be pointed out that neither stringWithFormat nor description will protect you from malicious code that passes in a bogus object.  The bogus object can always implement it's own "description" method to propagate bogosity.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that's what I meant. I'm guessing someone saw the explanation for why showing raw input in `NSLog` (ie `NSLog(string)` vs `NSLog(@"%@", string)`) was bad and assumed this would fix it in the general case.

Comment: My guesses; a poor copy/paste leftover; a programmer in too much of a hurry; or a programmer who doesn't understand ObjC.

Comment: @thegrinner -- I've seen this idiom far too often, in different code from different people.  It seems to be mainly due to a mistaken belief that certain values (such as label text) must always be "formatted", and, once ensconced in someones code it tends to spread to other methods, then get copied by others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pros and Cons of using \[NSString stringWithString:@"some string"\] versus @"some string"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275131/pros-and-cons-of-using-nsstring-stringwithstringsome-string-versus-some)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The argument that is passed in could be any subclass of string, including NSMutableString. This code creates an immutable copy of it. This means that you can store the returned string without having to worry about someone else modifying it.

A better way of doing this would be:

```
NSString *string2 = [string copy];
```

According to the [NSCopying Protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCopying/copyWithZone%3a):

> The copy returned is immutable if the consideration “immutable vs.
>   mutable” applies to the receiving object.

Comment: I like this answer. From examining the usage, I doubt it was the intent, but it does make sense as a desirable effect

Comment: I agree with @jszumski - if I were going to write something to that effect, I would use `copy`.

Comment: doesn't `[string copy]` return an Object of the same class as `string`, while the intent here is to only ever return an immutable string?

Comment: @James, no, `-copy` always returns the immutable variant of the class (if it has one). Only `-mutableCopy` will return the mutable variant.

Comment: Well TIL. I did browse the NSString reference and couldn't see any mention of this behaviour, but the NSCopying reference is very clear. I've added a link to my answer.

Comment: Using `copy` also has a different behavior when a `nil` argument is passed to the method. Using `stringWithFormat:` would result in a `@"(null)"` string, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Is there not also the difference between `copy` and `stringWithString` as to what object is responsible for releasing the copy (we're using MRR, as the project was started before ARC and it's never been worth the time to update it)

Comment: That's correct, `copy` transfers ownership to the caller, whereas `stringWithString` returns an autoreleased object.

Comment: I have discovered a case in the project where `string2` does not respond to length and crashes. When I opened up the object in the debugger I got `(NSString *)`, but on deeper inspection `isa=(Class)__NSCFBoolean`. This was not an issue with string format but it is with copy. What's going on?

Comment: Is `string` the same? In that case, someone has probably done a bad cast. If you wanted to really be sure, you could start with `NSAssert([string isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])` (not tested).